# To get values from 2D array

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have used this query to retrieve the dates for one particular user's approved leaves -

```
LeaveRequest.where(user_id: 6).where(status: 1).pluck(:from_date, :to_date)
```

and I'm getting this array as result -

```
[[Mon, 12 Sep 2016, Fri, 16 Sep 2016], [Tue, 06 Sep 2016, Tue, 06 Sep 2016], [Thu, 01 Sep 2016, Fri, 02 Sep 2016], [Tue, 30 Aug 2016, Wed, 31 Aug 2016]]
```

what I want is to fetch all the dates as well as the dates between 12 Sep 2016 and 16 Sep, 2016 (13th 14th and 15th).

Comment: Are the array results strings? Because otherwise the array doesent make too much sense?

Comment: @MuntasirAlam, well the dates are of "date" datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you mean something like this

```
require 'date'
#This is to simulate your current Array
current_array = 5.times.map {|n [Date.new(2016,n+1,1).<<(1),Date.new(2016,n+1,1)]}
#map the 2 dates to a Range
new_array = current_array.map{|start_date,end_date| (start_date..end_date)} 
new_array.first.class
#=> Range
```

Calling `to_a` on the Range will blow it out into all the dates between `start_date` and `end_date`

With a rails you could do something like

```
class LeaveRequest
  def self.user_requested_ranges(user_id, status_id)
    scoped.
      where(user_id: user_id, status: status_id).
      pluck(:from_date, :to_date).
      map do |from_date, to_date|
        #optionally to output the full Array in each Range you could use 
        #(from_date..to_date).to_a  
        (from_date..to_date)
      end
  end
end
```

Then call as

```
LeaveRequest.user_requested_ranges(6,1)
```

Comment: @sharma_a my answer still applies. `pluck` will return an `Array` and you can convert that `Array` to an `Array` of ranges. I will add a rails way for you just to make this clearer.